# Reset Running Sum to Zero on encountering specific value in a column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have Student Attendance information Date-wise as if Attended on a particular day then the value is 0, if not then 1. I want to have a running sum that shows consecutively how many days a student has missed. So the running sum has to reset when it encounters 0. How I can achieve this in Tableau.

Comment: I'd play around with something like - IF [attendence] > 0 THEN PREVIOUS_VALUE([attendence]) END

Comment: Thanks Bob. I have tried similar logic and was able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

After so many trial and errors I finally got to this expression and it seems to be working fine after testing.

```
IF ATTR([Attended]) != 0 
THEN IF FIRST() = 0 # This IF is basically for the first value to be displayed as 1 instead of 2 (1 + 1)
     THEN 1 
     ELSE SUM([Attended])+PREVIOUS_VALUE(SUM([Attended]))
     END
ELSE SUM([Attended])-SUM([Attended]) # Reset on 0
END
```

There might be a simpler logic, but this is working for me.

Hope it works for others too(make sure to delete the Comments in the expression if used in Tableau!!!)